# how to parse a string to spider from another script

Tags: python, windows, web-crawler, scrapy

I am new to python and scrapy . 
I am running the scrapy-ctl.py from another python script using 
*subprocess* module.But I want to parse the 'start url' to the spider from 
this script itself.Is it possible to parse start_urls(which are 
determined in the script from which scrapy-ctl is run) to the spider? 
I will be greatful for any suggestions or ideas regarding this....:)

Thanking in advance....

Answer (score 2):

You can override the `start_requests()` method in your spider to get the starting requests (which, by default, are generated using the urls in the `start_urls` attribute).